# Pseudocode algorithm for variables' signs static analysis - Check the sign of each operation

Tags: algorithm, haskell, ocaml, static-analysis

I want to do static sign analysis on variables (ints only).

Example : I have the possible signs of two variables and the operation

A Positive + A positive = A positive
`[Pos] + [Pos] -> [Pos]`

A Positive or Zero + A positive = A Positive
`[Pos; Zero] + [Pos] -> [Pos]`

A Positive or Zero or Negative * Zero = Zero
`[Pos; Zero; Neg] * [Zero] -> [Zero]`

Etc...

My variables' signs are coded as Lists / Arrays.

A positive or zero variable will be coded as [Pos; Zero] A negative variables will be coded as [Neg] A positive, negative or zero variable will be coded as [Pos; Neg; Zero] Order doesn't matter [Pos; Zero] is the same as [Zero; Pos]

I need to do this in OCAML, but you can help in any language / pseudocode.

Here is my idea :

```
let sign_operation (op:op) (l_expr: sign list) (r_expr: sign list): sign list = 
  match op with 
  | Add -> (match l_expr, r_expr with 
      | [Pos], [Pos] -> [Pos]
      | [Pos], [Zero] -> [Pos]
      | [Zero], [Pos] -> [Pos]
      | [Pos], [Neg] -> [Neg;Zero;Pos]
      | [Neg], [Pos] -> [Neg;Zero;Pos]
      | [Neg], [Zero] -> [Neg]
      | [Zero], [Neg] -> [Neg]
      | [Neg], [Neg] -> [Neg]
      | [Zero], [Zero] -> [Zero]
      | _ -> failwith "no")

  | Sub -> (match l_expr, r_expr with 
      | [Pos], [Pos] -> [Neg;Zero;Pos]
      | [Pos], [Zero] -> [Pos]
      | [Zero], [Pos] -> [Neg]
      | [Pos], [Neg] -> [Pos]
      | [Neg], [Pos] -> [Neg]
      | [Neg], [Zero] -> [Neg]
      | [Zero], [Neg] -> [Pos]
      | [Neg], [Neg] -> [Neg;Zero;Pos]
      | [Zero], [Zero] -> [Zero]
      | _ -> failwith "no")

  | Mul -> (match l_expr, r_expr with 
      | [Pos], [Pos] -> [Pos]
      | [Pos], [Zero] -> [Zero]
      | [Zero], [Pos] -> [Zero]
      | [Pos], [Neg] -> [Neg]
      | [Neg], [Pos] -> [Neg]
      | [Neg], [Zero] -> [Zero]
      | [Zero], [Neg] -> [Zero]
      | [Neg], [Neg] -> [Pos]
      | [Zero], [Zero] -> [Zero]
      | [Neg;Zero;Pos], [Zero] -> [Zero]
      | [Zero], [Neg;Zero;Pos] -> [Zero]
      | _ , [Zero] -> [Zero]
      | [Zero] , _ -> [Zero]
      | _ -> failwith "no")

  | Div -> (match l_expr, r_expr with 
      | [Pos], [Pos] -> [Pos]
      | [Pos], [Zero] -> [Error]
      | [Zero], [Pos] -> [Zero]
      | [Pos], [Neg] -> [Neg]
      | [Neg], [Pos] -> [Neg]
      | [Neg], [Zero] -> [Error]
      | [Zero], [Neg] -> [Zero]
      | [Neg], [Neg] -> [Pos]
      | [Zero], [Zero] -> [Error]
      | [Neg;Zero;Pos], [Zero] -> [Error]
      | [Zero], [Neg;Zero;Pos] -> [Zero]
      | _ -> [Error])

  | Mod -> (match l_expr, r_expr with 
      | [Pos], [Pos] -> [Pos]
      | [Pos], [Zero] -> [Error]
      | [Zero], [Pos] -> [Zero]
      | [Pos], [Neg] -> [Error]
      | [Neg], [Pos] -> [Error]
      | [Neg], [Zero] -> [Error]
      | [Zero], [Neg] -> [Error]
      | [Neg], [Neg] -> [Error]
      | [Zero], [Zero] -> [Error]
      | _ -> [Error])
```

This doesn't work for any variable with two or more possible signs.

If I have a variable [Pos; Zero; Neg] Minus [Pos; Zero], this won't be matched in my patterns. Trying every possible permutation in every possible order will be too long.

Can you suggest a better way to do this ?

Sorry if I couldn't get myself understood well, feel free to ask any question and thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you write

> A Positive or Zero + A positive = A Positive `[Pos; Zero] + [Pos] -> [Pos]`

How do you know this? Did you attend a school that taught you specifically what you get if you add a positive-or-zero number to something? Of course not. You broke it down into simpler cases, reasoning as follows:

1. The first number might be positive. In that case, I know that Pos+Pos = Pos
2. The first number might be zero. In that case, I know that Zero+Pos = Pos.
3. Therefore, across all values that the first number might hold, the result is either Pos or Pos.
4. Of course, we can simplify that to always being Pos.

Write a program that reasons in the same way. Instead of looking at a pair of lists of signs all at once, write a function for each operation that handles just a single sign for each operand, yielding a list of possible results. Call that function on each possible pair of signs represented by the input lists, then combine the results.

For example.

```
signOp Add x y = case (x, y) of
  (Zero, r) -> [r]
  (l, Zero) -> [l]
  _ | x == y -> [x]
    | otherwise -> [Pos, Zero, Neg]
```

Comment: I could just split my matchings into 5 functions, one for each sign, and send them all possible pairs of signs and join right ?

Comment: You could use 5 separate functions if you like. It's not really any different from one function: `op Add x y = ...; op Mul x y = ...;` is functionally the same as ``add x y = ...; mul x y = ...`, because `add = op Add`.

Answer (score 1):

The functional way to approach this is as follows:

```
let compare (s0 : sign) (s1 : sign) : int =
   match (s0,s1) with
   | (x,y) when x = y -> 0
   | (Neg, _) | (_, Pos) -> 1
   | (Pos,_) | (_,Neg) -> -1

(* flatten and remove duplicates *)
let join ( xs : (sign list) list) : (sign list) = 
   List.sort_uniq compare (List.flatten xs)

let add (s0 : sign) (s1 : sign) : sign list = 
   match (s0,s1) with
   | (x,y) when x = y -> [x]
   | (Pos, Zero) | (Zero, Pos) -> [Pos]
   | (Neg, Zero) | (Zero, Neg) -> [Neg]
   | (Pos,Neg) | (Neg, Pos) -> [Pos;Neg;Zero]

let add_list (sl : sign list) (s : sign) : sign list =
   join (List.map (add s) sl)
  
let add_abstract (sl0 : sign list) (sl1 : sign list) : sign list =
   join (List.map (add_list sl0) sl1)
```

You might have to be more careful with non-commutative operations like substraction and division.

---

If you know about monads, here is the OCaml way of doing this:

```
(* "let*" is "bind" or ">>=" in Haskell *)
let (let*) (sl : sign list) (f : sign -> sign list) : sign list =
  join (List.map f sl)

let add_list (sl : sign list) (s : sign) : sign list =
  let* s0 = sl in
  (add s s0)

let add_abstract (sl0 : sign list) (sl1 : sign list) : sign list =
  let* s0 = sl0 in
  let* s1 = sl1 in
  (add s0 s1)
```

Comment: Thanks man, I will look it up in detail when I’m on my pc. This is the same method as the answer above right ? I can’t think it through by mind

Comment: Actually it's not, because the answer above doesn't show how to define a generic `add : sign list -> sign list -> sign list`